# How to work with subheads and baseline grid in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with subheads and baseline grid in InDesign. I want them to have different **space before** and **space after** values. But I also want my body text to have consistent baseline grid. It's pretty easy when you have only one subhead per page, but what to do if I have multi-level subheads?

I prepared something that pictures my problem.

In this example baseline grid is set to 15 pt increment. Space before value for both of subheadings is set to 15 pt and space after is set to 7,5 pt. This works fine, but body text is not aligned with the baseline grid. It's easy to loose control over the grid.
[image: Good margins]
And this is the second example. Body text sticks to the baseline grid, but this causes that the space before and space after values are not true (they're in fact equal because the text jumps to the next baseline.
[image: Bad margins]
Do you have any solution for this problem? Preferably one that doesn't require turning off the baseline grid for the body text? The only thing I came up with is to create margins that can be divided by baseline grid value (in this case: 15 pt). Then I could make the upper margin (space before) lets say 20 pt and the lower margin 10 pt. But sometimes it's too much, so I'm looking for a method that would give me more control over the whitespace.

Comment: I think you've covered both options in your question! Either you have the combined margins at a multiple of the baseline grid or you set the body to align to the baseline regardless.

Comment: This is in fact mathematically impossible. As long as you have only header at a time, you can use baseline shift as mentioned in Dritan’s answer, but as soon as you have a Header 1 directly followed by a Header 2 (or 2 followed by 3), it is no longer possible to maintain the same consistent spacing both above and below each level while also aligning body text to the baseline grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last option is to work with baseline shift for subheads while keeping on the baseline grid. 
See image below. The subhead has baseline grid option ON, yet its above the line by 3pt

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set up baseline grid 1/2 of the leading for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

¿Or maybe setting up baseline grid ⅓ of the leading value for extra flex but a cluttered baseline grid screen?

Comment: This completely negates the purpose of the baseline grid, though, which is to make sure that lines are aligned to each other across spreads.

Comment: Shifting the subheads position also depends of the number of lines that integrates them

Comment: Yes, but if you then have a heading that takes up, say, 18pt in total, the lines following that heading will be 6pt off compared to the lines on the facing page if there’s no heading on that page.

Comment: I don’t see how that would fix anything. And what do you mean by “use a layer to complete the grid”?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.designersbookshop.com

Comment: I don’t think you’re understanding the problem here. Imagine you have a spread, a left and a right page, with a baseline grid of 3pt, leading 12pt. All lines on the left page match up exactly with those on the right page. Now add a heading which takes up a total of 30pt (12pt space before, 6pt after) between lines 10 and 11 on the left page. Line 11 will now be 42pt beneath line 10, 162pt from the top. On the right page, line 11 is 132pt from the top, line 12 144pt, line 13 156 pt, and line 14 168pt from the top – none at 162pt. The lines on the left and right pages are out of alignment.

Comment: You're completely right, when you take a fraction of a line with a sudivided baseline, it modifies in a negative way, as you cleverly says, this completely negates the purpose of the baseline grid, to align al over the document. My apologies, and I appreciate from you this info, in order to experiment with subheads also with different line numbers. ¿Can you be so kind to bring some solutios to this? My respect. Really, I was out of focus. Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to do it so that the same spacing works out for headings that cover different numbers of line unless the leading for the header is either exactly the same as the leading for the body copy or a whole-number multiple of the body copy leading.                               https://vimeo.com/3671746